# Delphi High DPI switch between own scaling and Windows scaling

Tags: delphi, dpi, hdpi

Some of my customers want to be able to scale my application manually (when Windows dpi is set to 96), so I had to implement scaling. Unfortunately these customers cannot go with setting Windows DPI to an other value and let WIndows scale my app because some very important applications they use do not behave well at all on resolutions <> 96 DPI.

I managed to make my Delphi 10.1 application scale quite well even on 200% but the higher the factor becomes the more some proportions become "not so nice looking". Many 3rd party components need special treatment for scaling and even then do not scale 100% accurate. Although applications scaled by windows look a little blurry on high resolutions, all proportions are 100% accurate and imho the app looks much more professional.

So I asked myself whether it is possible to create a setting that allows to tell Windows to do the scaling as a default and only scale on my own if the customer wants a scaling that is different from the current Windows scaling. This setting is hosted in the Windows manifest of the executable that is read on start of the application. Is there a way to change it at runtime (early startup of the application)? Creating two executables with different manifests is surely no good solution.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is the setting you mention `<dpiAware>`? If so, see remarks in [SetProcessDpiAwareness](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn302122(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, i will try that!

Comment: Why was my question voted down?

Comment: Probably because of the same reason with the existing close vote: "unclear what you're asking". I was not very sure either about suggesting the link I gave, but I took my chances.

Comment: @MichaSchumann Don't bother with the down votes. People many times feel they need to do something but don't know what and they down vote, vote to close on non-reasonable reasons. Anyway, thanks for sharing the answer. Very helpful

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to Sertac Akyuz I found a solution to my problem. In the Initialization part of the unit containing the scaling code I can switch between DPI-Awareness and Non-DPI-Awareness. It is important not to have this setting in the application manifest, which can be achieved by supplying a custom manifest like this (use control decoration and run with rights of current user):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
 <dependency>
   <dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity
       type="win32"
       name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
       version="6.0.0.0"
       publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
       language="*"
       processorArchitecture="*"/>
   </dependentAssembly>
 </dependency>
 <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
   <security>
     <requestedPrivileges>
       <requestedExecutionLevel
         level="asInvoker"
         uiAccess="false"/>
       </requestedPrivileges>
   </security>
 </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

This is the actual code switching depending on a registry key:

```
// Set DPI Awareness depending on a registry setting
with TRegIniFile.create('SOFTWARE\' + SRegName) do
begin
  setting := readInteger('SETTINGS', 'scale', 0);
  Free;
end;
handle := LoadLibrary('shcore.dll');
if handle <> 0 then
begin
  setProcessDPIAwareness := GetProcAddress(handle, 'SetProcessDpiAwareness');
  if Assigned(setProcessDPIAwareness) then
  begin
    if setting < 2 then
      // setting <2 means no scaling vs Windows
      setProcessDPIAwareness(0)
    else
      // setting 2: 120%, 3: 140% vs. Windows
      // The actual used scaling factor multiplies by windows DPI/96
      setProcessDPIAwareness(1);
  end;
  FreeLibrary(handle);
  // Get windows scaling as Screen.PixelsPerInch was read before swiching DPI awareness
  // Our scaling routines now work with WinDPI instead of Screen.PixelsPerInch
  WinDPI:= Screen.MonitorFromWindow(application.handle).PixelsPerInch;
end;
```

The last line of this snippet retrieves the current DPI for the current monitor as screen.pixelsperinch seems to be initialized before and does always return 96 as for a non dpi aware application. I use the value of winDPI in all subsequent scaling calculations and it works perfect.

Comment: After thinking all over once more I came to the conclusion that my approach is much more complicated than necessary. I think I can set the app non dpi aware and scale on top if the user requests it. This will avoid  high scaling factors on devices like Surface or my Lenovo 900s if I scale by 140 % and the device needs an other 200 % resulting in 280% on e. g.  Surface pro.

Comment: My solution may help someone searching for a possibility to switch between non-dpi-aware and dpi-aware at runtime. I (=blockhead) overlooked the possibility to combine Windows scaling (being non-dpi-aware) and my own scaling (for e.g. for light visualliy impaired people). It works well now and proportions are fine as my maximum scaling is 140%.